# Assigning Values to Multiple Elements?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I am writing my first code in numpy. I want to know if there is an easier way to assign values to multiple elements in an array since I'm using the same equations multiple times for the same array.

```
>>>ahp_c = np.ones(ahp_axis, dtype = np.float64)
[1., 1., 1., 1.]
[1., 1., 1., 1.]
[1., 1., 1., 1.]
[1., 1., 1., 1.]

>>>x = 1
>>>ahp_c[0][1] = (float(ps1) * x / x)
>>>ahp_c[1][0] = (x / float(ps1) * x)

>>>ahp_c[0][2] = (float(ps2) * x / x)
>>>ahp_c[2][0] = (x / float(ps2) * x)

>>>ahp_c[0][3] = (float(ps3) * x / x)
>>>ahp_c[3][0] = (x / float(ps3) * x)

>>>ahp_c[1][2] = (float(s1s2) * x / x)
>>>ahp_c[2][1] = (x / float(s1s2) * x)

>>>ahp_c[3][1] = (float(s1s3) * x / x)
>>>ahp_c[1][3] = (x / float(s1s3) * x)

>>>ahp_b[3][2] = (float(s2s3) * x / x)
>>>ahp_b[2][3] = (x / float(s2s3) * x)

[[1.         2.         3.         4.        ]
 [0.5        1.         0.2        6.        ]
 [0.33333333 5.         1.         7.        ]
 [0.25       0.16666667 0.14285714 1.        ]]
```

Comment: What are the `ps` and `s2s3` values are? Also, please describe more the desired outcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For a start:

```
>>>ahp_c[0,1] = (float(ps1) * x / x)
>>>ahp_c[1,0] = (x / float(ps1) * x)

>>>ahp_c[0,2] = (float(ps2) * x / x)
>>>ahp_c[2,0] = (x / float(ps2) * x)

>>>ahp_c[0,3] = (float(ps3) * x / x)
>>>ahp_c[3,0] = (x / float(ps3) * x)
```

then

```
ps = np.array([ps1,ps2,ps3], dtype=float)
x = 1.0
for i in range(0,3):
    ahp_c[0,i+1] = ps[i]*x/x
    ahp_c[i+1,0] = x/ps[i]*x
```

and on to:

```
ahp_c[0,1:] = ps*x/x
ahp_c[1:,0] = x/ps*x
```

That use of x/x`looks odd, especially when`x=1`, but I'm focusing on the multiple statements, not the math.  I'm trying to find a common pattern so we don't have to use explicit indexing, replacing it first with a loop, and then with slice/range indexing.